# UIWebView not loading content when it is passed from an UITableView in iOS6, but works perfectly in iOS5

Tags: xcode, uitableview, ios5, ios6, uiwebview

First of all I would like to thank you reading this and helping me out if you know the answer, I am a bit of a newby to iOS and there is an issue that is driving me crazy.

I have an App that works perfectly in iOS5, it has an UITableVIewController and clicking on a row takes you to an UIView with a UIWebView. The idea is that the URL of the webpage to load is passed from the UITableViewController in this way.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{  
    if (([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ViewWeb"])) {

      WebViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
      detailViewController.title=parameter;

       detailViewController.detailItem = parameterURL;
     }
}
```

Then in the WebViewController I use the following code. I declare everything in the .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WebViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>{
   IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
   NSString *detailItem;
}

@property(strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *detailItem;

@end
```

And In my .m I use the following code to load the URL:

```
@interface WebViewController ()

@end

@implementation WebViewController

@synthesize webView;
@synthesize detailItem;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

//Create a URL object.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:detailItem];

//URL Requst Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];

}
```

This is working perfectly fine in the iOS5 simulator, but in iOS6, the UIWebWiew remains blank and doesn't load up. I have read this solution [UIWebView not loading URL when URL is passed from UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465370/uiwebview-not-loading-url-when-url-is-passed-from-uitableview) but placing the code in the (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated does not solve the issue. It works perfectly fine if I hard code the URL, so I am totally lost as to how to solve this.

Thank you very much in advance, I know everyone here is really busy and the fact that great guys take a few minutes to hep me is something amazing.

Comment: Did you check that `prepareForSegue:sender:` is called in iOS6 by setting a breakpoint?

Comment: Yes, I did. It is working perfectly. In fact, I retrieve the parameter correctly in the WebViewController (I can see it with NSLog)

Comment: Ok - did you try printing detailItem in `viewWillAppear:` of the destination viewController?

Comment: Yes, I tried that too :(. It shows up perfectly with NSLog but if I place the code there it doesn't load either

Comment: Did you check that webView is not NULL? `NSLog(@"webView: %@",webView);`

Comment: I just tried and it is NULL. But I have linked it correctly in the storyboard.. how can I solve this? Really, thank you so much for your time

Comment: I think this is caused by XCode 4.4+ which generates _webView for you when using `@synthesize webView`. Would you please do a NSLog on _webView? (note that this will only hold for iOS6)

Comment: I get this with _detailItem webView: <UIWebView: 0xa993b10; frame = (0 0; 768 867); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0xa993bc0>>. Should I call the request from viewWillAppear with _webView?

Comment: try to use self.webView or do a `@synthesize webView = _webView;`

Comment: I synthesized like you said, webView does not show null using -webView. But it still doesn't load the code whether I place it in viewDidLoad() or in viewDidAppear().