# UIWebView staying blank until I hard code the URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I am writing an App where I pass a Link as a NSString from a TableView to my DetailView. The String gets passed correctly, as I can see it in the log. The problem is, that the WebView just stays blank; unless I hard code any URL in. Even the ones that I can see in the log by just copy pasting them. What am I missing? Any help is greatly appreciated. Here's a sample log output and my code. I also checked this thread, where the guy hab the exact same problem as me, but none of the solutions posted there where helpful. [UIWebView not loading URL when URL is passed from UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465370/uiwebview-not-loading-url-when-url-is-passed-from-uitableview)

> 2013-06-17 13:19:52.147 Feuerwehr[1661:c07] http://oliverengelhardt.de/ffw_app/Einsaetze/GB0505/index.html

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *urlString = url;
    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
    NSLog(urlString);

}
```

Comment: NSLog requestObj also and myURL.

Comment: check whether `requestObj.url` is null..?

Comment: Check whether the delegate is properly assigned or not.

Comment: The sample code works for me... Check the webView is not null? It is bounded using IB? The webView's delegate is bounded too? The device is online?

Comment: Is the 'url' variable property synthesised?, if so then do like this NSString *urlString = self.url;

Comment: Thank your everyone for your quick responses. Sadly, your solutions did not work. I have tried them all. Again the webView works fine, when I hard code the URL like this: NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com"];

Comment: I think it's properly synthesised I did it like this in the .h file '@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *url;'   and like this in the .m file '@synthesize url;'

Comment: are you using the correct URL format e.x http://www.google.co.uk. Note url protocol http must be declared

Comment: Well the String I get is: http ://oliverengelhardt.de/ffw_app/Einsaetze/GB0505/index.html Is the http declared somewhere else? it's without the spaces of course.

Answer (score 0):

I think you stringUrl is nil when it loads (so it doesn't get passed. Break point view did load and see the value of the urlstring

Based on what you've said, your url isn't formatted correctly

Comment: I get this value when I print it to the console: 'Printing description of urlString:
http://oliverengelhardt.de/ffw_app/Einsaetze/GB0505/index.html'  or when i do po it get '(lldb) po urlString
$2 = 0x082bf190 http://oliverengelhardt.de/ffw_app/Einsaetze/GB0505/index.html'

Comment: Nslog and see what the string says. It not nil then, but we dont know the value

Comment: NSLOG gives me '2013-06-17 14:22:52.147 Feuerwehr[1661:c07] http://oliverengelhardt.de/ffw_app/Einsaetze/GB0505/index.html'

Comment: no, it's there stackoverflow just cuts it off for some reason... :D

Comment: Ok. Check that you added the webview delegate. (Right click on webview in storyboard, it should say delegate. Also add <UIWebViewDelegate> to your .h file

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31868/discussion-between-waf-and-oengelha)

Answer (score -1):

i think you are missing delegate
 self.webView.delegate = self;

Comment: Thank you. It did not change anything.

Comment: u should check NSLog(url) , what it prints  and can u tell what is the type of url

Comment: try   [self.webView loadHTMLString:urlString baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];

Comment: This, at least does not give me a blank screen, but it just shows the link on the screen, but not the website.

Comment: No, it's just text, no link.

Comment: try this
 NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];

    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];

    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];

Comment: in url at the end u r getting extra &#39 which is not allowing to show url in webview

Comment: This code shows nothing again. @alok how do i get rid of this?